# Making numbers palindromic

Tags: java, beginner, programming-challenge, palindrome

This is a challenge I [found here](http://www.reddit.com/r/dailyprogrammer/comments/38yy9s/20150608_challenge_218_easy_making_numbers/). You're suppose to list how many steps it takes to convert a number to a palindromic number, where each step consists of adding number to the reverse of itself. For example, `196196871` takes 151 steps and gives me `3588816724276188853`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    private Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Main() {
        String input = in.nextLine();
        ArrayList< Long > targets = new ArrayList< Long >();

        // Checks if the ENTER key was pressed. ENTER is the exit key of this program.
        while(!input.equals(""))
        {
            targets.add(Long.parseLong(input));
            input = in.nextLine();
        }

        for(long target : targets)
            System.out.println(target + " gets palindromic after " + getPalSteps(target) + " steps: " + convertToPal(target));          
    }

    public long reverse(long number) {
        long reverse = 0;
        long n = number;
        while (n != 0)
        {
            reverse *= 10;
            reverse = reverse + n % 10;
            n /= 10;
        }
        return reverse;
    }

    public boolean palindrome(long number) {
        return reverse(number) == number;
    }

    public long convertToPal(long number) {
        if (number == 196)
            return -1;

        while (!palindrome(number))
        {
            number = reverse(number) + number;
        }

        return number;
    }

    public long getPalSteps(long number) {
        int steps = 0;

        if (number == 196)
            return -1;

        while (!palindrome(number))
        {
            number = reverse(number) + number;
            steps++;
        }

        if(steps > 10000)
            System.out.println("Lychrel number!");

        return steps;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

Comment: 3588816724276188853 looks like a palindromic number to me, in what way is it not working perfectly?

Comment: The challenge output says "196196871 gets palindromic after 45 steps: 4478555400006996000045558744". My output is different, it takes more steps and gives me a different number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a number to its reverse, its value approximately doubles, on average.  If you do it 10000 times, you should get a result that is very roughly 2<sup>10000</sup> times the original. That will certainly overflow a `long`, which only holds values below 2<sup>63</sup>.  You need to either

- lower the iteration limit
- check for overflow
- use `BigInteger`
- reinvent arithmetic for large numbers using strings or arrays

---

The use of OOP is awkward and inappropriate. Constructing an object should just involve just allocating and initializing some memory to model something. Your `Main()` constructor, though, is the entire input, calculation, and output loop of the program.

Your program isn't object-oriented at all. Just make everything static, and merge the constructor code into the `main()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Overall your code looks very good. It's very readable and easy to understand.

**Don't Do Work Twice**

My only real suggestion is to not do the work twice. You're first checking how many steps it takes to convert the number to a palindromic number, and then doing it again to actually convert it. It should all happen in one step, like this:

```
Pair<long> convertToPal(long number)
{
    int steps = 0;

    if (number == 196)
    {
        return new Pair<-1, 196>;
    }

    while (!palindrome(number))
    {
        number = reverse(number) + number;
        steps++;
    }

    if(steps > 10000)
        System.out.println("Lychrel number!");

    return new Pair<steps, number>;
}
```

Note: there may be better ways to return 2 values than a `Pair`. You could create a class that holds the resulting number and the number of steps, or whatever you feel is appropriate. ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832472/how-to-return-2-values-from-a-java-function) for more on that.)